# Setting grid column divs to be the exact same height in tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

Was wondering if I am missing something here - I have 4 divs that are in a grid. Just asking about the desktop view here. One of the divs has more content (the 2nd) but I can't get the others to be the same size. Have tried a good amount of things :) Code and tailwind play link below. Thanks

```
   <div class="mt-3.5 px-[3rem] lg:mt-[4.5rem] mx-auto grid grid-cols-12 gap-x-0.63 gap-y-2.75 py-8 grid-rows-1">
      <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-3 order-1 text-lg lg:order-1">
<div class="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-detailBorder pb-2 px-1 flex flex-col items-center text-center" id="data-widget-academic-calendar">
  <div class="-mt-1.5 w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-blue flex items-center justify-center text-2xl leading-6 text-white" aria-hidden="true">

  </div>

  <p class="mt-0.5">
    <span class="block font-medium text-xl leading-6">
      Academic Calendar
    </span>

    <span class="block mt-1 font-semibold text-4xl text-blue">
      PH DATA
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-12 lg:col-span-3 order-4 text-lg lg:order-2">
       <div class="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-detailBorder pb-2 px-1 flex flex-col items-center text-center" id="data-widget-student-to-faculty-ratio">
  <div class="-mt-1.5 w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-blue flex items-center justify-center text-2xl leading-6 text-white" aria-hidden="true">
  </div>

  <p class="mt-0.5">
    <span class="block font-medium text-xl leading-6">
      MORE TEXT HERE MORE TEXT HERE
    </span>

    <span class="block mt-1 font-semibold text-4xl text-blue">
      PH DATA
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-6 lg:col-span-3 order-2 text-lg lg:order-3">
<div class="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-detailBorder pb-2 px-1 flex flex-col items-center text-center" id="data-widget-majors-offered">
  <div class="-mt-1.5 w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-blue flex items-center justify-center text-2xl leading-6 text-white" aria-hidden="true">

  </div>

  <p class="mt-0.5">
    <span class="block font-medium text-xl leading-6">
      Majors Offered
    </span>

    <span class="block mt-1 font-semibold text-4xl text-blue">
      PH DATA
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-6 lg:col-span-3 order-3 text-lg lg:order-4">
  <div class="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-detailBorder pb-2 px-1 flex flex-col items-center text-center" id="data-widget-minors-offered">
  <div class="-mt-1.5 w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-blue flex items-center justify-center text-2xl leadng-6 text-white" aria-hidden="true">

  </div>

  <p class="mt-0.5">
    <span class="block font-medium text-xl leading-6">
      Minors Offered
    </span>

    <span class="block mt-1 font-semibold text-4xl text-blue">
      PH DATA
     </span>
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/3wrTScjb1D

Comment: Urgh tailwind... Anyway, I notice `w-full` is in use so I guess `h-full` is the equivalent for 100% height.

Comment: thanks that may have worked https://play.tailwindcss.com/K6AJ8poZNR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tailwind you can use the class `h-full` to set an element’s height to 100% of its parent. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height

So in your case your four divs...

```
<div class="w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-detailBorder pb-2 px-1 flex flex-col items-center text-center ...
```

...should be given the class 'h-full` too:

```
<div class="h-full w-full rounded-lg border border-gray-detailBorder pb-2 px-1 flex flex-col items-center text-center ...
```

Comment: appreciate the help @Moob !